# Network won't train if using output tensor of tf.while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a custom loss which uses `tf.while_loop()`. The code is as below. If I use the output of tf.while_loop(), my network just won't train, seems to get stuck forever. But if I use the original variable name it works just fine. Why is this happening? Are we not supposed to use new variable names for output tensors of tf.while_loop()?

```
k = tf.constant(0)
i = tf.constant(val0)
sum_t = tf.constant(0,dtype=tf.float32)


while_condition = lambda k,i,sum_t: tf.math.less(k,val1)

def body(k,i,sum_t):
    tf.add(sum_t,val2)
    def f1(k,i):
        lambda:tf.add(k,1)
        lambda:tf.math.subtract(i,val1)
        return(k,i)
    def f2(k,i):
        lambda:(tf.add(i,1))
        return(k,i)
    tf.cond(tf.math.greater_equal(i,dim_t),lambda:f1(k,i),lambda:f2(k,i))
    return(k,i,sum_t)


new_k,new_i,loss2 = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, [k,i,sum_t])

loss = loss2 #network won't train with this
loss = sum_t #network trains fine with this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop isn't doing anything, it just loops forever. You are declaring some lambda functions but you are not using them, and you do some operations with the input tensors but do not use the result of those operations. The body function just returns the same things it is receiving. I think what you want is something like this:

```py
k = tf.constant(0)
i = tf.constant(val0)
sum_t = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)

while_condition = lambda k, i, sum_t: k < val1

def body(k, i, sum_t):
    def f1(k, i):
        return k + 1, i - val1
    def f2(k, i):
        return k, i + 1
    k, i = tf.cond(i >= dim_z, lambda: f1(k, i), lambda: f2(k, i))
    return k, i, sum_t + val2

new_k, new_i, loss2 = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, [k, i, sum_t])
```

Comment: wow, what a big blunder. Thanks a lot! Yes I fixed the loop now. But same as before if I use `loss2` the network training just gets stuck. Will it be wrong to assign `sum_t = sum_t +val2` and use `sum_t` in my loss?

Comment: @momo Well `sum_t` is a constant initially, so you cannot train on that. I don't know what `val2` is, but if it is another constant then I'm not sure how you would use it to train anyway. About the loop, I don't know the values of `val0`, `val1` and `dim_z`, I _think_ the loop should eventually finish in any case, but it could take many iterations.

Comment: updated my question code with the values I'm trying to run the loop with. I tried seeing if it's going into an infinite loop but k reaches 128 and that should break the loop. Am I doing something wrong still?

Comment: @momo Your updated code has a couple of minor mistakes (an extra parenthesis in the `tf.cond` line, `sum_z` in the `return` statement of `body` should probably be `sum_t` and `val0` is still undefined, although I suppose that comes from somewhere else), but after fixing them it runs for me, that is, I can compute `loss2` and it gives a value. As I said, whether that loss value can be used or not for training depends on the relationship between (in the updated code) `val0` and the variables in the model.

Comment: thanks a bunch @jdehesa! Turns out I just needed some patience. It takes longer amount of time than expected, but does run.